# Error when creating project in AndroidStudio

Tags: android

Whenever I try to make a new project in Android, I get this error

```
Failed to import Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
       Build file 'C:\Users\vvina_000\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplicationProject\MyApplication\build.gradle' line: 9
       A problem occurred evaluating project ':MyApplication'.
       A problem occurred evaluating project ':MyApplication'.
       Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
       com.google.common.collect.Maps
       Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

I opened up the build.gradle file and all it says is: 
`// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules", there is no line 9.`

Comment: Had the same problem. Solved it by upgrading AndroidStudio to the latest version.

Comment: I checked, it is in the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem recently. 
Solution was to remove Gradle and reset AndroidStudio:
(OSX Mountain Lion)

1. Show hidden files
   execute in terminal: defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
   restart Finder (Option+RightClick on Finder > Relaunch)
2. Delete gradle files:
   ~/.gradle
3. Reset AndroidStudio
   Add lines to /Application/Android Studio.app/bin/idea.properties:
    idea.config.path=~/.AndroidStudioPreview/config
    idea.system.path=~/.AndroidStudioPreview/system
4. Restart AndroidStudio.

Then everything worked like a charm :D